# Use array of strings as argument for pluralization in .stringsdict

Tags: ios, swift, nslocalizedstring

We're trying to make a typing indicator that displays one or two names depending on how many people are typing at a time. So the use cases are:

- Person1 is typing
- Person1 and Person2 are typing
- Several people are typing

I know it's possible to pass an array of strings mapped to `[CVarArgType]` as the arguments for `String(format:, arguments:)`, but am wondering if/how it's possible to handle that array logic in the `Localizable.stringsdict` file to achieve the result described above. Maybe with something similar to this?

[image: stringsdict_implementation]

Do I need to know the exact count of the array arguments for something like this to work?

Comment: I think this tutorial might help you - https://crunchybagel.com/localizing-plurals-in-ios-development/